# how to make texture2d from just point array.(XNA, Farseer Physics Engine)

Tags: xna, polygon, texture2d, farseer

I use Farseer Physics Engine for pump simulation.
In there Example, they always use texture2d format.
But that pump shape is given just Point(x,y) Array.

I want to make polygon or texture2d from that point array.

PolygonTools.CreatePolygon method need int[] and width, not point[].

I don`t know how to make polygon by int[] and width.

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you wish to create a texture2d from array... hm... i will try explain how will i try this, this is not working example just hint how to do it.

first you need to find with and height, so find max X and max Y to create blank texture.

```
Texture2D blankTexture = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, maxX, maxY, false, SurfaceFormat.Color);
```

then loop over texture and set pixel color from your array

```
for(int i=0; i<blankTexture .width; i++)
{
  for(int j=0; j<blankTexture .height; j++)
  {
    // pixel = texture.GetPixel(i, j); 
    // loop over array, and if pointX in array = i and pointY in array = j then
    pixel.Color = Color.White; //
  }
}
```

i think this is quite cpu expensive way... but it could work.

Comment: Thank you. 
I tried this way.
but, there is no GetPixel method.
and I have only points on outline of pump rotor,
not filled body, not connected line.
But this is of help to come up other way
i will try other way.
thank you.